# is .limit() Method from Firstore is smart enough to detect new data limit depends on the changing int variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, get

i have `StatefulWidget` which contains `Future.Bulder Widget` and listener controller method in Listview.builder like so

```
class Messages extends StatefulWidget {


  const Messages({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MessagesState createState() => _MessagesState();
}


class _MessagesState extends State<Messages> {


  int limit = 10 ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller!.addListener(listener);
    super.initState();
  }

  listener(){
    if (controller!.offset >= controller!.position.maxScrollExtent && !controller!.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        limit = limit+10;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

        body: FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").limit(limit).get(),
    builder: (context , AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> messages ) {
    if (!messages.hasData) {
    return Center(
    child: circulearProgress(),);
    }
    return ListView.builder(
    controller: controller,
    itemCount: messages.data!.docs.length ,
    itemBuilder: (context , int index){

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = messages.data!.docs [index] ;

    return Text(documentSnapshot['textMessage']);
  
    );
    }
    )
    );
    }
  }
```

ok now .get() will get 10 docs as a default also  i handle the listener to increase 10 to limit variable once the user scroll to down page then stream get other 10 docs besides the previous old 10 docs .. Now the question is

**Will .get() read only the new 10 docs in every time that user scroll down or  will it read again the old previous 10 docs with new 10 ones ??**
if not how can avoid to read the old docs again in the same my example ..

any edit to my code with solution sample will be thankful ..

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question -

> Will .get() read only the new 10 docs every time that user scrolls down OR will it read again the old previous 10 docs with new 10 ones?

Yes, it will read the previous docs and the new 10 docs. Here you are increasing the limit and fetching the data based on the new limit, so it will fetch the number of documents that is specified in the limit() method. So each time the limit is increased it will fetch the previous set of documents along with the new 10 documents.

If you want to get pagination like, fetch the first 10 documents and then fetch only the next 10 sets of documents, then I would suggest you to use the `limit` method with the `startAfterDocument` method and pass an existing document as the `startAfterDocument` parameter. You can find more about limiting and using `startAfterDocument` [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#start--end-cursors).

To get a detailed description of pagination in Firestore you can go through [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU&t).